# AccountService.Sound bug?

Tags: sound, ubuntu, indicator-sound

Just installed the very latest version of elementaryOS today. Things went well, except for this annoying volume notification issue! Every 10 seconds, a notification pops up in the top right showing me the volume level. As if I was changing it, but I'm not. This is super distracting and annoying.

GIF showing the UI symptom (wait for it haha):

[image: animation of the issue]

Found some messages in `syslog` that seem related:

```
Feb 19 00:27:18 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (epiphany:3372): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
Feb 19 00:27:18 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (epiphany:3372): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
Feb 19 00:27:18 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (process:1652): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.346405 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Feb 19 00:27:19 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (process:1652): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.346405 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Feb 19 00:27:20 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (process:1652): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.226410 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Feb 19 00:27:21 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (process:1652): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.346405 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Feb 19 00:27:30 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (process:1652): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.226410 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Feb 19 00:27:31 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (process:1652): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.346405 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Feb 19 00:27:36 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (process:1652): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.226410 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Feb 19 00:27:38 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (process:1652): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.346405 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Feb 19 00:27:39 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (process:1652): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.346405 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Feb 19 00:28:00 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (process:1652): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.226410 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Feb 19 00:28:01 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (process:1652): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.346405 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Feb 19 00:28:02 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (process:1652): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.346405 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Feb 19 00:28:06 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (process:1652): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.226410 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Feb 19 00:28:07 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: (process:1652): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.346405 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Feb 19 00:28:07 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: me '4' not found in GtkStack
Feb 19 00:28:07 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: #033[101m#033[97m[FATAL 00:26:27.737065]#033[0m app_center_widgets_banner_banner_widget_get_package: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
Feb 19 00:28:07 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: #033[93m[WARNING 00:26:32.737653]#033[0m [Gtk] Child name '5' not found in GtkStack
Feb 19 00:28:07 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: #033[101m#033[97m[FATAL 00:26:32.737708]#033[0m app_center_widgets_banner_banner_widget_get_package: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
Feb 19 00:28:07 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: #033[93m[WARNING 00:26:37.739052]#033[0m [Gtk] Child name '1' not found in GtkStack
Feb 19 00:28:07 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: #033[101m#033[97m[FATAL 00:26:37.739112]#033[0m app_center_widgets_banner_banner_widget_get_package: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
Feb 19 00:28:07 desktop-linux gnome-session[1387]: #033[93m[WARNING 00:26:42.740948]#033[0m [Gtk] Child name '2' not found in GtkStack
```

Any assistance would be so appreciated! I'm really close to just installing Debian but I want to stick with elementaryOS if possible.

Comment: This starts happening right after restart and logging in? Have you installed any third party software that might try to influence your volume?

Comment: @PeterUithoven yes, this happens immediately after a clean install. No third party software at all. If I restart, it happens right after the restart as well.

Comment: By chance, was this happening in the live session prior to install or did you pick to install straight away?

Comment: @linux_tim this happened in the live session prior to install and also after install

Comment: I'm guessing that manipulating the volume up or down does not stop the eratic pop-up, correct?

Comment: @linux_tim correct. In fact, the erratic pop-up is always set at the same volume level, no matter what I had just adjusted it to. The volume shown on the erratic pop-up doesn’t seem to be the actual system volume though

Comment: One last question...have you applied all updates via AppCenter or the command line?

Comment: Ok so I tried removing indicator-sound and rebooting. The erratic pop up is gone but now the volume indicator in the menu bar flashes with the same frequency and the sound cuts out for a split second when that happens.

Comment: @linux_tim ask as many questions as you need! Want to fix this. I’ve installed updates via AppCenter, all of them. And double checked with an apt update and upgrade.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73385/discussion-between-linux-tim-and-michael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug that was reported some time ago on Launchpad which mimics the issue being posed here. Here is the [Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1585084).

There seems to be what is a viable workaround for this issue in comment number 20 below the initial report.

Other fixes shown to be successful include updating pulseaudio to version 10 or above however there seems to be less verification as to whether or not that is a true fix.

In working with the user posing the original question, the workaround in the Bug Report has worked.

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue while leaving headpones plugged in.

For posterity, the solution from the above "#20" answer:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1585084

```
dualshock3nerd (dualshock3nerd) wrote on 2017-01-24: #20

I found a more viable workaround based on comment #18 by Anthony that still lets you use your headphone jack provided you have an unused front microphone jack.
    Install alsa-tools-gui
    Run hdajackretask
    Override "Green Headphone, Front side" to "Not connected"
    Override "Pink Mic, Front side" to "Headphone"
    Click "Apply now"
    Click "Install boot override" to make this permanent
From now on, just plug your headphones in the front microphone jack instead of the front headphone jack and you're golden. Speakers still get automatically muted when you plug in your headphones.
This is much more viable to me as I just use a USB microphone anyway.
I tested this for a few days and this bug never reappeared.
```

Also note that the missing DBus service is created in the accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas package
https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnome/accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas